# Missing associated label error when binding to [attr.for] and [id] in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, webstorm

I am using WebStorm IDE which is working well alerting on problems with web accessibility.

Unfortunately it does not recognize Angular binding attributes.

In my html I have below code:

```
<label [attr.for]='id' >My Label</label>
<input [id]='id' />
```

In my TS file:

```
id = 'name'
```

After compiling, the above input will have an associated label. Unfortunately WebStorm is complaining `Missing associated label`.

Is there a way WebStorm can be set to recognize this input as having associated label without disabling the check?

The problem also occurs when I bind to `[attr.aria-label]`. Same error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, please follow [WEB-33969](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33969) and linked tickets for updates.

For now, I can only suggest disabling the **HTML | Accessibility | Missing associated label** inspection in **Settings | Editor | Inspections**